# How do I get the call back function to log the value of the data attribute with mouseover?

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener, mouseover

So I have a 'li' list here that I have selected, and I'm using a for loop to add a mouseover event listener to each of those tags.

```
<ul>
    <li data-animal="horse">Animal 1</li>
    <li data-animal="dog">Animal 2</li>
    <li data-animal="cat">Animal 3</li>
</ul>
```

And I've come to a halt, because the *call back function* should log the **value** of each **data attribute** when the mouse move over it. How can I achieve this?

```
const mouseOverLoop = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < mouseOverLoop.lenght; i++) {
  mouseOverLoop[i].addEventListener("mouseover", hoverOver);
}
function hoverOver() {
  console.log();
}
```

Comment: If you look into the documentation you see that the function passes an event object, change to `function hoverOver(evt)` and console log that object... when you want just try without looking into the docs, do `function hoverOver(a, b, c)` and check if any is not `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- A typo, it should be `mouseOverLoop.length` (not `lenght`)
- The `console.log()` doesn't have a string to log.

You can use the event's `target` property to identify the proper element, and the `getAttribute` method to get the attribute value.

```js
function hoverOver(e) {
   console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-animal'));
}
```

```js
const mouseOverLoop = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < mouseOverLoop.length; i++) {
  console.log(mouseOverLoop[i]);
  mouseOverLoop[i].addEventListener("mouseover", hoverOver);
}
function hoverOver(e) {
   console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-animal'));
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-animal="horse">Animal 1</li>
    <li data-animal="dog">Animal 2</li>
    <li data-animal="cat">Animal 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, I see now that I forgot to add a string to log in the question, but I also wasn't sure how to get the data attribute there. Thank you very much for the help!! Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul id="animals">
    <li data-animal="horse">Animal 1</li>
    <li data-animal="dog">Animal 2</li>
    <li data-animal="cat">Animal 3</li>
</ul>
```

```js
document.getElementById("animals").addEventListener("mouseover", function({ target: { dataset } }) {
  if (dataset.animal) {
    console.log(dataset.animal);
  }
});
```